# Can i specify the bottom right corner of a text box in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there any way I can specify the bottom right corner coordinates of a text box using matplotlib?

the code for my box is:

```
plt.text(x_max-2.7e+3, y_min+1e+5, box_text, style='italic',
        bbox={'facecolor':'white', 'alpha':0.5, 'pad':10})
```

and that produces this for the current plot:

[image]

however, those coordinate values were found by trial and error, and the ranges and orders of magnitude for my data will be different for different plots as well.. I would like a way that I can specify the coordinates of the bottom right corner of the text box to be (x_max, y_min) and it would automatically draw the box from there.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not surprisingly, the answer is yes. However, there is a much simpler way to do what you want. Let me begin with a bit of background first.

[`plt.text`](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.text) is just a wrapper that creates a [`mpl.text.Text`](https://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text) object on the current axes. Unfortunately, `Text` anchors itself based on the text alignment properties, and you can't specify an arbitrary point of the text box to anchor. This is unfortunate because there is a whole [tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html) on how to position text using the axis [transform](https://matplotlib.org/api/transformations.html#matplotlib.transforms.Transform) (coordinate system) instead of the data.

Fortunately, there are some helper classes in `matplotlib.offsetbox` that do exactly what you want. These classes are described in the [tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/text/annotations.html#placing-artist-at-the-anchored-location-of-the-axes), and a couple of relevant examples are shown in the sample gallery [here](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/axes_grid1/simple_anchored_artists.html) and [here](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/userdemo/anchored_box01.html). The particular class you are looking for is [`mpl.offsetbox.AnchoredText`](https://matplotlib.org/api/offsetbox_api.html#matplotlib.offsetbox.AnchoredText). You would set up your text box like this:

```
from matplotlib.offsetbox import AnchoredText

...

text_box = AnchoredText(box_text, frameon=True, loc=4, pad=0.5)
plt.setp(text_box.patch, facecolor='white', alpha=0.5)
plt.gca().add_artist(text_box)
```

`frameon=True` makes the [`Patch`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Patch.html#matplotlib-patches-patch) behind the text visible. `loc=4` lines up the bottom right corner of the box with that of the `Axes`. `pad` is now in units of fractions of your font size. [`plt.setp`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.setp.html) is a utility function to set multiple properties on an bunch of objects at once. The first argument in this case is just a single patch, but normally you would pass in a list of things to operate on.

Since you have to add an `AnchoredText` directly to an [`Axes`](https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes), I would recommend switching to the [Object Oriented API](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_summary.html#the-object-oriented-api). Your code would look very similar, but you would have more direct access to the underlying objects. You would create your figure and axes using something like [`plt.subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html). Then you would plot your data using the methods of `Axes` that correspond to the usual [pyplot methods](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_summary.html#the-pyplot-api). Your code would look like this:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.offsetbox import AnchoredText

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(...)

text_box = AnchoredText(box_text, frameon=True, loc=4, pad=0.5)
plt.setp(text_box.patch, facecolor='white', alpha=0.5)
ax.add_artist(text_box)
```

Comment: thanks so much, that was really helpful and very well presented!

Comment: actually, its now aligned my text to the right of the text box.. is there any way i can align the box to the right of the plot but not the text to the right of the box?

Comment: My fault. Looks like I led you astray there. Instead of all that junk with transforms, you just need an `AnchoredText`. Here's the example: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/misc/anchored_artists.html. I'll rewrite my answer in a little bit.

Comment: Wait, there's a much better example here: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/axes_grid1/simple_anchored_artists.html

Comment: I'll have to submit a PR to get those merged.

Comment: @guskenny83. I am going to completely rewrite my answer now that I've done all that research. Will ping you when I'm done.

Comment: @guskenny83. All done. It's actually even simpler than I had first mentioned. No need to deal with transforms at all.

Comment: how do you change the `zorder` on this?

Comment: @pretzlstyle. Great question. I believe every artist maintains its own zorder, but it's been years, so I'm honestly not sure.

Comment: @pretzlstyle. Looking at the docs, it seems that `AnchoredText` takes a zorder parameter

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use a transform.  For example,

```
ax.text(1, 0, box_text, transform=ax.transAxes, ha='right', va='bottom', 
         style='italic', bbox={'facecolor':'white', 'alpha':0.5, 'pad':10})
```

will be drawn in the lower right corner.  For other transforms, [see link](https://www.alphacodingskills.com/matplotlib/matplotlib-transformations.php)